# Python — curses, setting the color of a border

Tags: python, curses

From the Python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/curses.html) and [howto](https://docs.python.org/dev/howto/curses.html) pages it's clear how to color text: by first adding strings to a window and then using `chgat()` to assign a color-pair to the desired characters in that window.

What isn't clear to me is how to change the color of a box or border, which are made visible using `box()` or `border()`. **Edit**: using `chgat()` on the whole window does not seem to affect that window's border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's *one* way to color text, but generally not the *best* way. I'd suggest, instead, using attrset(), and *then* adding strings or borders. The border and text should then both be affected, and it's less overhead.

Comment: A working example would be nice, though I realize this is from a "few" years back.

Answer (score 0):

William's suggestion to use *attrset()* was good, but since I've just started using Python curses, I had to research a little before I was able to implement it.

If anyone is as lost as I was, here is a working example of a program that shows a blue colored border:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import curses

def main(stdscr):
    curses.use_default_colors() # Make possible to use -1 in init_pair()
    # To define colors, it's necessary to program a color pair. We are using
    # the color pair 1. The -1 parameter below references the default color.
    curses.init_pair(1, curses.COLOR_BLUE, -1)

    stdscr.clear()
    begin_x = 1
    begin_y = 1
    height = 3
    width = 15
    window = curses.newwin(height, width, begin_y, begin_x)
    # Set the color and draw a box. Note that a refresh() is still necessary
    window.attrset(curses.color_pair(1))
    window.box()
    # Reset the colors. The color pair 0 is always white on black
    window.attrset(curses.color_pair(0))
    window.addstr(1, 3, "Box Title")
    window.refresh()

    curses.curs_set(0) # Invisible cursor
    window.getkey()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    curses.wrapper(main) # Restore configuration after the program's end
```

I saved the text with the name of `colored_box.py` and executed with `python colored_box.py`. This code is tested with Python version 3.10.12.

By the way, I suspect that *color_pair(0)* is not the correct option to preserve the default foreground and background color, but I don't have the means right now to check this, since my terminal is white on black.